# Webpack: There's some JavaScript code in the compiled file even when the source file is empty

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix). Out of the box, the included app.js file bootstraps quite a few dependencies like jQuery, Bootstrap-sass etc.

When I delete everything in the app.js file, why is there still some code in the compiled js file? Is it a Webpack thing? Even after running `npm run production` it stays there and I haven't been able to figure out what it does or what it means and not knowing makes me really uncomfortable.

Here's the code that gets left behind:

```
! function(n) {
function t(e) {
    if (r[e]) return r[e].exports;
    var o = r[e] = {
        i: e,
        l: !1,
        exports: {}
    };
    return n[e].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, t), o.l = !0, o.exports
}
var r = {};
t.m = n, t.c = r, t.i = function(n) {
    return n
}, t.d = function(n, r, e) {
    t.o(n, r) || Object.defineProperty(n, r, {
        configurable: !1,
        enumerable: !0,
        get: e
    })
}, t.n = function(n) {
    var r = n && n.__esModule ? function() {
        return n.default
    } : function() {
        return n
    };
    return t.d(r, "a", r), r
}, t.o = function(n, t) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n, t)
}, t.p = "", t(t.s = 3)
}([function(n, t) {}, function(n, t) {}, function(n, t) {}, function(n, t, r) {
r(0), r(1), n.exports = r(2)
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack adds some code to the bundle to handle modules correctly. This code is referred to as *webpack bootstrap*. If you want to know what the code does, you should look at the non-uglified version. There are plenty of comments and it's generally easy to get the gist of it, although you don't need to understand every detail.

Here is the non-uglified code (this is the entire bundle with an empty module):

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {



/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

It's basically mimicking the `require` from Node.js while also handling ES modules. All this is to make it work in the browser (all browsers for that matter). See also [Node.js - Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).